# USB C on PCB wiring

Tags: usb

This might be a very stupid question but I'm gonna ask it anyway.
Below is a picture of a USB C is there anyway using the internal test pads of connecting up an internal storage usb stick from them points? And would it stop the that USB C connection charging the device and allowing it to connect to a windows pc?
It's a hand held android device

USB C:
[image: USB C]

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are wanting to put two USB devices in parallel.  You can't do that. The data lines will fight each other, they are not a bus on the connector.

To `split` a USB port, you need to use a **USB Hub**

They are really cheap [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/usb-hub/s?k=usb+hub)

> The drivers for the data lines on USB devices are not "tri-state", so they always "power" the I/O lines. If you connect two data wires directly together they will fight each other and whomever is the strongest will (probably) take precedence.

Reference: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/connecting-usb-devices-in-parallel.495200/

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend doing this or even testing it on a USB-C connector.  Maybe someone with more electrical engineering knowledge can speak up, but this is probably a bad idea.

USB-C not only connects data, but power as well.  Since different USB-C devices draw different amounts of power - and some can draw a lot of power - you run the risk of damaging both the controller and the device.

You could connect to an older type USB 2 (or 1.x) type A connector and draw power directly it, as it is only 4 pins and only sends out 5v.  If you connected just power and ground, then you can charge a device.

Comment: A hub is not really ideal for this situation. I did think because I'd be piggy backing the usb 2 part of the connection id get away with it?